# Why do I get a 404 when I post a form to a URL but not if I use window.location to go there?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, dom

If I post to a URL (changing it to https) by using the form, I get a 404 error (despite the address bar showing the **correct** address):

```
//This ends up at a 404 page (BUT showing the correct address in the address bar)
form.setAttribute( "action", window.location.href.replace( "http:", "https:" ) );
form.submit();
```

If I instead do it with `window.location`, it shows the page correctly:

```
//This shows the page correctly
window.location = window.location.href.replace( "http:", "https:" );
```

Even changing the form to `method="GET"` results in the 404 error

Why does the first one result in a 404 error?

Comment: Whats running on the server? Maybe it doesnt handle post requests? When you set window.location it does a get request.

Comment: are the methods the same?

Comment: @DanielA.White I started using "POST" but even setting the form to `method="GET"` still results in 404

Comment: @LJ_1102 It's Wordpress. And even using `method="GET"` results in the 404 error

Comment: What exactly is the action, maybe it expects you to provide a redirect uri when the request was successful.

Comment: @LJ_1102 See my answer below. It's a wordpress bug

Answer (score 0):

In the first you are sending a form to the server which it does not want to receive

In the second example you are just simply changing the url in the address bar which just sends an http(s) get

Answer (score 0):

It was a weird Wordpress bug: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-pops-after-custom-form-submission-by-post#post-1291358

If your form contains a field called "name", it will fail!